# PMF of random variable|Expectation|A.Hayter 4th edition

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

my question is as follows->

A consultant has six appointment times that are open, three on Monday and three on Tuesday. Suppose that when making an appointment a client randomly chooses one of the remaining open times, with each of those open times equally likely to be chosen. Let the random variable X be the total number of appointments that have already been made over both days at the moment when Monday’s schedule has just been completely ﬁlled. (a) What is the state space of the random variable X? (b) Calculate the probability mass function and the cumulative distribution function of X.

->Now, I know the state space would take the values {3,4,5,6} as they said **total** number of appoinments over both days **att the moment** when M's schedule is filled so 3 is for when only M has the appointments, 4 when 1 extra is added  and so on. Moving on, I am facing some problems with the **pmf** of this random variable.

->Here is what I found, on slide number 13 of this site;
https://slideplayer.com/slide/4387098/
the PMF is as follows;
$$P(X=3)=\frac{C_3^3}{C_3^6}$$
$$P(X=4)=\frac{C_3^4-C_3^3}{C_3^6}$$
$$P(X=5)=\frac{C_3^5-C_3^4}{C_3^6}$$
$$P(X=6)=\frac{C_3^6-C_3^5}{C_3^6}$$

-> what I am facing trouble in is understanding how the pmf came to be like that? I still don't understand how it all fits in. The answer at the back of my book matches, but how does it make intuitive sense? How do I derive the answer for P(X=4) and beyond then? Why is it like the way it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $k\in\{3,4,5,6\}$ let the agenda for the first $k$ appointments have the shape of a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with cardinality $k$ where $1,2,3$ represent appointments on Monday and $4,5,6$ represent appointments on Tuesday.

Then there are $\binom6k$ agenda's in total and $\binom{3}{k-3}$ of them contain $\{1,2,3\}$ as a subset.

The set of the agenda's that contain $\{1,2,3\}$ can be recognized as the event $\{X\leq k\}$.

The probability on an agenda that contains $\{1,2,3\}$ equals:$$\frac{\binom{3}{3-k}}{\binom{6}{k}}=\frac{3!k!}{(k-3)!6!}=\frac{\binom{k}{3}}{\binom{6}{3}}$$

So found is now that:$$P(X\leq k)=\frac{\binom{k}{3}}{\binom{6}{3}}$$and from this it follows directly that:$$P(X=k)=P(X\leq k)-P(X\leq k-1)=\frac{\binom{k}{3}-\binom{k-1}{3}}{\binom{6}{3}}$$

---

I think that there is a more direct explanation but at the moment I can't find it.

Comment: i see. Thanks a lot. so I basically go backwards from the c.d.f to the pmf. this makes much more sense now.

Comment: You are very welcome.